# Make an Object's scope outside the block

Tags: c#, oop

Can we initialize an Object inside a block or function (without declaring it before) so that it can be used outside its block too...?

Here Type2 is a derived class from Type1

for eg:

```
if(a==b)
{ Type1 obj = new Type1();}
else
{Type2 obj = new Type2();}

obj.getFunction();
```

I have a base class USER derived class ADMIN, have to create an object according to the role of the user while he logs in and use that object afterwards so thath i dont need to check the role of the user every time.. (am a newbie)

**IS THIS POSSIBLE??**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable can only be of one type or another - otherwise how would the compiler know what member access to allow afterwards?

If there's some common base type (base class or interface) which declares `function`, that should be the type of the variable:

```
BaseType obj;
if (a == b)
{
    obj = new Type1();
}
else
{
    obj = new Type2();
}
obj.Function(); // Name fixed to follow conventions
```

This would be simpler as:

```
BaseType obj = a == b ? (BaseType) new Type1() : new Type2();
obj.Function();
```

If they're *really* different types, so you're effectively calling entirely separate methods, then *either* you'll need to declare the variable within each block and call the method there, or if you're using C# 4 or later you *could* use dynamic typing:

```
dynamic obj = a == b ? (dynamic) new Type1() : new Type2();
obj.Function();
```

You should really be trying to think about whether this is a genuinely-common function, in which case it *should* be declared in a base type, or whether it's just a coincidence that you've got two functions with the same name, in which case trying to treat them the same way is a bad idea. (Imagine you refactor one type to change the method name, for example...)

Comment: do u mean that Type1 and Type2 should be inherited from BaseType??

Comment: @Hybridzz: Potentially, yes. You haven't really given us enough information to say.

Comment: I have a base class USER and derived class ADMIN, have to create an object according to the role. ie; if role is 1 then i have to create an ADMIN object say, obj, Else i have to create an object of type USER named obj itself.

Comment: This is working  

USER obj;  
if (role == 1)  
{
    obj = new ADMIN();
}
else
{  
    obj = new USER();  
}  
obj.getDetails();

Comment: @Hybridzz: Please *edit the question* with more details, and "this is not working" is never enough of an explanation. Say in what *way* it's not working. (Also, please follow .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: but we cant call derived classes method. Its acting with the properties of base class only. :(

Comment: @Hybridzz: Sorry, I can't help you when you refuse to provide details in the question (as requested), instead just providing *some* information in the comments.

Answer (score 5):

Why not make simply execute the function on the scope? You can't access variables beyond the scope. (*Unless see Jon Skeet's answer (best player steps on the arena)...*)

```
if(a==b)
{ 
    TYPE1 obj = new TYPE1();
    obj.function(); 
}
else
{
    TYPE2 obj = new TYPE2();
    obj.function(); 
}
```

Comment: @Hybridzz: **Why** do you have to use it afterwards? You haven't given us enough information about your situation, basically. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 5):

> Can we create a variable inside a block or function (without declaring
>   it before) so that it can be used outside its block too...?

No you cannot do that. You have to define the variable outside the block so that you can access it outside as well.

Comment: ok, i needa know whtr this is possible some how. Thank you 4 ur answer

Comment: @Hybridzz, you have to define the variable outside the block to use it afterwards, thats it. Otherwise its not possible.